# How can I Remove the 'Possible Duplicate' Status on my questions?

Tags: support, questions

I've asked two questions recently, both of which were similar to, but also different from, previously asked questions.

The [first question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/25536/first-person-when-the-pov-is-not-the-protagonist) received a comment from Lauren Ipsum, saying it was a possible duplicate. No problems there; I would expect no less. The linked question was not an answer to mine. I edited my question to explain how.

The [second question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/25563/what-should-i-avoid-when-naming-characters) received the same comment from Mark Baker. This would be understandable as well, if I had not expressly stated within my question that it was not a duplicate of the exact question Mark Baker linked. I knew someone would think that, so I opted to save them the trouble.

That aside, the problem is this: Now that I've edited both questions, they still have a box on top saying that they 'may have an answer' with a link to the other question. I've edited and clarified that they do not, but that box still remains.

I think that message might be turning off viewers. They see that message, assume it is a duplicate, and go somewhere else. I could be wrong of course, but either way its getting to me.

**How can I get rid of that box?**

Note: The 'box' I am referring to is not the initial one that pops up, with the button to edit the question. This is a different box, and I see no way to get rid of it.

Comment: Claiming that your question is not a duplicate does not make it not a duplicate. Explain how it isn't. That way you may convince those that voted to close as duplicate to retract their votes.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this? I don't see it on the questions you linked to.

Comment: @what To my knowledge, votes-to-close can't be retracted but they *do* expire in time.

Comment: @NeilFein If you can't see the box that I'm seeing, then it might just be a question-author thing. Come to think of it, I've never seen one outside of my own questions, so that's probably the case. That more or less solves my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the "possible duplicate of" notice that appears at the top of the body of the question.  This notice is visible only to you.  It predates the "is this a duplicate?" dialogue that you also encountered, and I assume SE wanted the author to see something more prominent than a comment that might or might not even still be there.

I believe the notice persists so long as there's a pending "close as duplicate" vote indicating that question.  It should go away in time.  Meanwhile, it's not hindering other viewers of your question because they're not seeing it.

I can see the argument that once you've answered "no it's not" and edited, you don't need to see this any more.  If you want to propose a change to how the software works, please post a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).  You can post it here or on Meta.SE; it'll get more visibility there, but the team does monitor the per-site metas.  (I usually take my feature requests to Meta.SE in hopes of gathering cross-site support, in case that helps advance them.)

Answer (score 2):

These comments should be preserved.

Stack Exchange sites are generally okay with variations on a question. These discussions serve as a record of the discussion that the question was similar to another question; should we consider it a duplicate or not?

These discussions are generally retained so that other users, who might vote to close a question, can see the discussion. If a good case has been made that the question should be left open (or if it's been edited to no longer be a duplicate), they'll tend to avoid voting to close it.